# set variable to the current time and date symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to set a variable $time to the current time and then date following this format:
HH:mm:ss On day/month/year.

Could anyone help me to do that in symfony?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried with the built-in `date` function?

```
$time = date('H:i:s \O\n d/m/Y');
```

This should work until 2038 :) Both `O` and `n` need to be escaped, as they have a special meaning within the format string.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using Symfony2 and you are looking for a way to display a date, you can do this directly in your twig template with:

```
{{ "now"|date("H:i:s \O\n d/m/Y") }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Answer (score 4):

This is the same as in any other PHP application:

```
$time = new \DateTime();
echo $time->format('H:i:s \O\n Y-m-d');
```

The `\` before `O` and `n` are necessary to prevent `DateTime::format` from interpreting the characters as date codes and output them literally.